# Shopify - Check out button won't change even after code modification

Tags: html, ajax, button, shopping-cart, shopify

I'm using shopify and i'm got some trouble with my online store.
I wanted to set up a french store and replace in my cart "check out" by "commander" and "remove" by "retirer".

I went to "theme.liquid" and changed the code.

[image]
Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything, at least i don't get what i want. As you can see on the screenshot below, the "check out" and the "remove" are still showing up. They are eventually replace by "commander" and "retirer" as i wanted if i refresh the page and only if i do so. How can i modify the code so they are definitely replaced by the new values?

[image]
Thanks for helping

Regards

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only place in your code where this button appears? Your template code has comment tags around it, whereas the page source does not, which may signal that it's coming from somewhere else when you add a new product.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit cart.liquid instead of theme.liquid